# Does changing a method to add the hidden this pointer break binary compatibility?

Tags: c++, g++

Example code :

```
// Base.hpp
class Base
{
   public:
   void changeInternals();
   int readInternals();
   void printString(std::string& iString);

   private:
   int m_Internal;
};

// Base.cpp
void Base::changeInternals()
{
   m_InternalValue = 5;
}
int Base::readInternals()
{
   return m_InternalValue;
}
void Base::printString(std::string& iString)
{
   std::cout << iString << std::endl;
}
```

My understanding is that, under optimisation with g++, the first two member functions (changeInternal and readInternal) will have the 'this' pointer as part of the function arguments, so it can access the member variable m_Internal. However, the third member function, printString, doesn't need to view the member variable and as such won't have the this pointer in the arguments?

In that case, if we changed thus:

```
 void Base::printString(std::string& iString)
 {
    std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(m_Internal) << std::endl;
 }
```

The member function would now require access to m_Internal, and would therefore require the caller of this function to put the value of the 'this' pointer into the register.

I would expect this to break binary compatability, but I cannot seem to find this in any list of "binary-compatability gotchas". Is there a requirement that all member functions, regardless of touching the internals or not, have the this pointer? Examining gdb output in cores (I can't copy/paste here sadly :(, sorry) implies not.

For the purpose of this question, please assume that inlining is not taking place here (through GCC never_inline attributes)

Comment: The implicit parameter is always there. Otherwise it would be impossible to use pointers to member functions uniformly.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Not true. Consider a compiler which marks the function as "`this` not needed", a pure optimization. A caller which **knows** it's calling such a function may then leave out the initialization of `this`, whereas a caller through a pointer must assume it's needed. In general, you can't assume that a call through a pointer is exactly identical to a direct call. In particular, with multiple inheritance PTMF's often need stubs/trampolines.

Comment: @Mike B: Are the implementations of the methods in the header in your real code? If so, then there is not much sense thinking about binary compatibility. This makes only sense if you put the implementations to a .cpp file so it is not seen by the "using compiler". If the implementation is in the header you need to compile all using code if you change it...so binary compatibility is of no interest.

Comment: @RüdigerStevens The actual implementation of the code is in a seperate .cpp file, yes - the example in the question looks like the .hpp, which I did for brevity - but yes, it's misleading. I will update the question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A member function is ALWAYS<sup>**[1]**</sup> called with the `this` pointer, whether it is used or not. This is so that the compiler doesn't have to "know" whether some function uses the `this` pointer or not. Consider the case where the function is included only as a declaration in a header file, and the actual implementation is compiled separately in a different source file - how would the compiler know? Or in the case where the function is virtual, and there are multiple possible classes, some of which use, and some of which don't use `this` (implicitly) inside the member function.

This does not apply to `static` member functions - that's part of the point of `static` member functions.

**[1]** Of course, in the case where the compiler can "see" the source code of the function, it may choose to inline the actual function, and if the `this` pointer is not being used, it can then be removed as part of the inlining process. But this is again not a break in compatibility.